# Django Rest Framework JWT "Authentication credentials were not provided."}

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt

I am trying to write a simple API that uses JWT tokens to authenticate.

My `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
   'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

And my View looks like this:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return JsonResponse({"username":str(request.user)})
```

Which really does nothing, but I don't even get there. I have registered the JWT Token provider as in the documentation with `url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token)` and I receive a token when I call this endpoint.

However, when I then make a request against my APIView (which contains the header `Authorization: JWT <my_token>` I always receive the following error:

`[Response]:  403   [Data]:  {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the token you used to call your view invalid?

Comment: No, I just receive it a second before and it also comes out as valid when I run a request against the token-verify endpoint

Comment: @JoSauderGH Were you ever able to get over this issue? I am facing the same problem and I do not know the way out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache as web server then add the following in apache `httpd.conf` file:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

This worked for me.